# C++ shared_ptr can't see member function from class type

Tags: c++, class, shared-ptr

I'm attempting to use shared pointers for the first time and I'm running into a problem that I can't access the member functions of Element from the pointer. I've looked at examples around the web, and it seems as though it should be possible to access the Element's functions, but I suspect I've done something wrong in setting up the pointers, but I can't work out what.

How do I access public member functions in Element from a shared_ptr? 
(I'm using Xcode 5.1.1)

```
#include <memory>    
#include <iostream>
class Element
{

private:
    std::string name;
    std::shared_ptr<Element> * firstChild;
    std::shared_ptr<Element> * lastChild;
    std::shared_ptr<Element> * nextSibling;

public:
    void addChild(std::shared_ptr<Element> * child)
    {
        if (lastChild != nullptr) {
            lastChild->setNextSibling(child); //Error: No member named 'setNextSibling' in 'std::__1::shared_ptr<Element>'
            lastChild = child;
        }
        else {
            firstChild = lastChild = child;
        }
    }

    void setNextSibling(std::shared_ptr<Element>* p)
    {
        nextSibling = p;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using pointers to shared pointers. That doesn't make sense. Replace all `std::shared_ptr<Element>*` with `std::shared_ptr<Element>` and you'll be fine.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. I knew it had to be something simple like that, but just couldn't see it.